# Retrofit2 Post запрос для получения tokena. Что я делаю не так?

Tags: retrofit2

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://client-api.instaforex.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
UserClient userClient = retrofit.create(UserClient.class);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.btn_login).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            login();
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.btn_secret).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getSecret();
        }
    });

}

private static String token;

private void login() {
    Login login = new Login("логин", "пароль");
    Call<User> call = userClient.login(login);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().getToken(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                token = response.body().getToken();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "login not correct :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error:(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private void getSecret() {
    Call<ResponseBody> call = userClient.getSecret(token);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().string(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "login not correct :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error:(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

---

```
public class Login {
@SerializedName("Login")
private String login;
@SerializedName("Password")
private String password;

public Login(String login, String password) {
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

---

```
public class User {
private String token;

public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}
```

}

---

```
public interface UserClient {
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("api/Authentication/RequestMoblieCabinetApiToken")
Call<User> login(@Body Login login);

@GET("api/Authentication/RequestMoblieCabinetApiToken")
Call<ResponseBody>  getSecret(@Header("Authorization") String autchToken);
```

}

Comment: Запрос должен быть таким:
{
"Логин": "PARTNERS_LOGIN",
"Пароль": "PARTNERS_PASSWORD"
} в ответ получаем токен "323e3f23r23f323f"